# How to describe parameters in DRF Docs

Tags: python, django, documentation, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework v3.6 built-in interactive documentation `django_rest_framework.documentation` (**not** `django-rest-swagger`).

Basically, I'm following [the official documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/) and use this in my URLset configuration:

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^", include_docs_urls(title="My API")),
    ...
]
```

Everything seems to work and I get a nice interactive documentation page, but I have a `ViewSet` with `lookup_field = "slug"` and one thing about the generated documentation bothers me:

[image: In "Path parameters", the description for "slug" parameter is empty]

I want to have some useful information it that description, like "an unique permanently-assigned alphanumeric ID" or something among those lines, but can't find any documentation where this data comes from.

There is a workaround but I really don't want to [define all the schema explicitly](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#explicit-schema-definition). I want to declare my classes with nice docstrings and have docs auto-generated. I've also found an suggestion to put `slug -- here goes the description` in the docstring but it doesn't seem work - the text just appears with the rest of the Markdown-formatted description.

So... I wonder about two things:

1. (A specific question) Where do I fill this path parameter description?
2. (More generic version of the same question) What's the best way to learn how schemas are auto-generated from code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Oh, I found it. Answering my own question.

DRF documentation isn't verbose on this matter (or I've missed the piece where it is), but it mentions [`rest_framework.schemas.SchemaGenerator` class](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.2/rest_framework/schemas.py#L257) and it seems that this class really does all the introspection stuff. Fortunately, the source code is well-structured and easy to read.

Those path fields are generated by [`get_path_fields`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.2/rest_framework/schemas.py#L517) method (I found it by tracing the execution path: `get_schema` → `get_links` → `get_link`), and I found that descriptions [come from model fields's `help_text`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.2/rest_framework/schemas.py#L540) attribute.

So in my model I've specified:

```
class MyResource(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(unique=True, help_text=_("unique alphanumeric identifier"))
    ...
```

And it worked!

Comment: This half works for me. It has no effect on object primary keys. Looking at the links you've provided, it should automatically work out the description based on the type of primary keys used (UUID in my case). It's just coming up as a blank sadly.

Answer (score 5):

One important thing was not still covered. It is true that a description comes from the `help_text` attribute, but this is not enough. I have found that the schema generator rely on [view's `queryset`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) attribute to determine a model. So, keep in mind that you need define it even if you don't need it. For example in case of using `APIView`.