# About django rest framework document, how custom the description of request params and add the field to post params?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[image]

In the auto-generate view by rest_framework.documentation,when I take the post test, there is no field to fill my params, and how to add the description of request params like the api of "delete>list"?

I can not get the ideas from the document:[Documenting your API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/)

Should I write some code at here?

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def Login(request):

    try:
        username=request.data['username']
        password=request.data['password']
    except Exception as error:
        return Response(str(error), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is None:
```

or :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^media/(?P<file_path>.*)', views.GetMediaFiles),
    url(r'^api/',include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='CLTools API Docs')),
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665108/6293466