# Django restframework documenting Views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, documentation-generation

My questions is:

how can i fill the field Description? in  tha table of Parameters in my docs page, here an example of my function and a screenshot how does it look

```
def delete(self, request, id_):
    repository = self.get_object(id_, owner=request.user)
    repository.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT, headers={"web_words": request.user.profile.web_words, "repo_words": request.user.profile.repo_words, "files": request.user.profile.files})
```

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664634/how-to-describe-parameters-in-drf-docs) what you are looking...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to describe parameters in DRF Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664634/how-to-describe-parameters-in-drf-docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DRF documentation isn't verbose on this matter (or I've missed the piece where it is), but it mentions [`rest_framework.schemas.SchemaGenerator` class](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.2/rest_framework/schemas.py#L257) and it seems that this class really does all the introspection stuff. Fortunately, the source code is well-structured and easy to read.

Those path fields are generated by [`get_path_fields`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.2/rest_framework/schemas.py#L517) method (I found it by tracing the execution path: `get_schema` → `get_links` → `get_link`), and I found that descriptions [come from model fields's `help_text`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.2/rest_framework/schemas.py#L540) attribute.

So in my model I've specified:

```
class MyResource(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(unique=True, help_text=_("unique alphanumeric identifier"))
    ...
```

Comment: Im trying with :  ```slug = models.CharField(unique=True, help_text=_("unique alphanumeric identifier"))```. but ```help_text=("unique description") ``` run only without ```_``` in case my function is pretty custom, doest work.

Comment: you need to import `_`  as  `from  django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`